# Can't run script without error - TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: error TS5109: Option 'moduleResolution' must be set to 'NodeNext

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, bun

When I run the following script:

```
"changed-specs": "find-cypress-specs --branch main --parent"
```

I get this TypeScript error:

```
/Users/george/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS5109: Option 'moduleResolution' must be set to 'NodeNext' (or left unspecified) when option 'module' is set to 'NodeNext'.

    at createTSError (/Users/george/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/george/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
    at /Users/george/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1379:34
    at Object.compile (/Users/georg/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1451:13)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/george/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/george/Documents/core-cypress/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 5109 ]
}
```

I'm now using bun as my package manager so that might be why? My other scripts are working fine. I haven't changed my TypeScript config in a long time, just the package manager. Is it just not possible to use some libraries with bun? I tried using "NodeNext" as mentioned in error but didn't fix it.

Config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
      "types": ["cypress", "node", "@cypress/grep"],
      "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }
```